# package poi.org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist

Tags: java, excel, apache

When I compile my code I get these errors:

```
CreateWorkBook.java:3: error: package poi.org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist
import poi.org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
                                        ^
CreateWorkBook.java:4: error: package poi.org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist
import poi.org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
                                        ^
CreateWorkBook.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
                ^
  symbol:   class HSSFWorkbook
  location: class CreateWorkBook
CreateWorkBook.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
                                            ^
  symbol:   class HSSFWorkbook
  location: class CreateWorkBook
CreateWorkBook.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                ^
  symbol:   class HSSFSheet
  location: class CreateWorkBook
CreateWorkBook.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                ^
  symbol:   class Iterator
  location: class CreateWorkBook
CreateWorkBook.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                         ^
  symbol:   class Row
  location: class CreateWorkBook
CreateWorkBook.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                ^
  symbol:   class Iterator
  location: class CreateWorkBook
CreateWorkBook.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                         ^
  symbol:   class Cell
  location: class CreateWorkBook
CreateWorkBook.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                                              ^
  symbol:   variable row
  location: class CreateWorkBook
10 errors
```

what do I do? I already looked in several places and I did not manage to correct these mistakes.

I compile my codes using: javac CreateWorkBook.java
and run the code using: java CreateWorkBook

(Sorry if my English is bad.)

Comment: [`import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html) - there is no `poi` at the start.

Comment: this import that you sent is already in the code and I still continue with the same erros. How do I start poi?

Comment: He's saying get rid of the imports that start with poi, they are invalid.

Comment: I get the same errors putting poi in front of imports

Comment: You should not be putting poi in front of the imports.

Comment: managed to compile but I can not run

Comment: @ClockWork how did you manage to compile? I'm trying the same but getting same errors.

Comment: are you using Maven?